Unable to cURL on some platforms, in particular DigitalOcean VPS
I am on Ubuntu 23.10 (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-27-generic x86_64) is not working, curl is 8.2.1 suspect is there is something on the machine.
I have two Virtual Private Servers (VPS) based on Digital Ocean service, and on both of these I'm unable to perform the following cURL command and receive a valid response (page source) with the same internal server error response:
curl -v -L -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)" https://www.chanel.com/it/profumi/p/114460/egoiste-eau-de-toilette-vaporizzatore

To note the -L option was used to follow the redirects, the above line provides a valid 200 response with the curl listing all the web page source code. Below is the full response I'm receiving:
curl -V
curl 8.2.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/8.2.1 OpenSSL/3.0.10 zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.5 libidn2/2.3.4 libpsl/0.21.2 (+libidn2/2.3.3) libssh/0.10.5/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.55.1 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.6.6
Release-Date: 2023-07-26
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd

curl -v -L -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)" https://www.chanel.com/it/profumi/p/114460/egoiste-eau-de-toilette-vaporizzatore
*   Trying 23.36.163.227...                                                                                                                                        
* TCP_NODELAY set                                                                                                                                                  
* Connected to www.chanel.com (23.36.163.227) port 443 (#0)                                                                                                        
* ALPN, offering h2                                                                                                                                                
* ALPN, offering http/1.1                                                                                                                                          
* successfully set certificate verify locations:                                                                                                                   
*   CAfile: none                                                                                                                                                   
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs                                                                                                                                           
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):                                                                                                                  
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):                                                                                                                   
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):                                                                                                           
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):                                                                                                                   
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):                                                                                                                   
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):                                                                                                                      
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):                                                                                                        
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):                                                                                                                     
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384                                                                                                            
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2                                                                                                                                  
* Server certificate:                                                                                                                                              
*  subject: C=FR; ST=le-de-France; L=Neuilly-sur-Seine; O=CHANEL SAS; CN=*.chanel.com                                                                              
*  start date: Dec 17 00:00:00 2023 GMT                                                                                                                            
*  expire date: Dec 17 23:59:59 2024 GMT                                                                                                                           
*  subjectAltName: host "www.chanel.com" matched cert's "*.chanel.com"                                                                                             
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1                                                                                               
*  SSL certificate verify ok.                                                                                                                                      
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use                                                                                                                           
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)                                                                                                                      
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0                                                                                   
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55d2c4ac4110)                                                                                                                  
> GET /it/profumi/p/114460/egoiste-eau-de-toilette-vaporizzatore HTTP/2                                                                                            
> Host: www.chanel.com                                                                                                                                             
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)                                                                                                            
> Accept: */*                                                                                                                                                      
>                                                                                                                                                                  
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):                                                                                                              
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):                                                                                                              
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing                                                                                                                            
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!                                                                                                        
* HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)                                                                                                   
* stopped the pause stream!                                                                                                                                        
* Connection #0 to host www.chanel.com left intact                                                                                                                 
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)   

I'm doing this only to test a machine connectivity since I'm having problem with php-webdriver with docker-selenium and the response was a 301 status page, so I did a test using cURL and looks like I found there is some underlying cause not related to selenium.

I wonder if its different builds between working and non working machines. Seems to work in ubuntu 20.04. Might be helpful to include curl -V output and Distro versions

@JourneymanGeek could you curl in Ubuntu 20.04 and received the actual source of the web page? I have added the OS in the question and I'm running on 23.1 while the working machine is just a windows pro 64bit not comparable though.

https://gist.github.com/JourneymanGeek/b7add9e90e2d8f99eaba29446c8ee4b3 that's what I got. I've included the curl and OS versions... and copy pasted the commands for reference.

@JourneymanGeek Looks like you used Ubuntu 22.04 and not 20.04 but I don't think it is related to Ubuntu, the result you are getting is the whole page source before eventual ajax calls, the same I'm getting on windows using -L I also had support test on Vultr VPS and it still replicates, maybe bad IP? The IP I used was checked against blacklist and it came out clean.

@S.W.G. did you ever arrive at a resolution here?

@vinsanity555 The problem is some webistes exclude requests from VPN, in paritcular popular ones such as DO or AWS. Selenium / puppeter are not the problem, you need some residential proxy service in the middle.
